# How to draw a semicircle on the edge of the window in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, graphics, drawing

I'm trying to draw a semicircle using msoShapeArc with AddShape. The semicircle needs to touch the top of the page.  To do this, I set the y value to -radius.  This works in C# using Graphics, but excel ignores the negative coordinate and brings the shape down to zero.

```
    Sub DrawArrowArc(CentX As Single, CentY As Single, radius As Single, Ang1 As Single, Ang2 As Single)
       Dim Arc        As Shape
       'Draw 90-degree arc with radius = Radius and center at (CenterX,CenterY)
       Set Arc = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeArc, CentX, CentY - radius, radius, radius)
       'Add arrowhead on clockwise end
       Arc.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadNone
       'adjust arrow to start at Ang1 and end at Ang2
       '(measured clockwise positive from vertical)
       Arc.Adjustments.Item(1) = 90 - Ang1
       Arc.Adjustments.Item(2) = 90 - Ang2
    End Sub

DrawArrowArc 0, -100, 100, 90, -90
```

I'm open to different ways of accomplishing this.  The circle doesn't need to be selectable or editable like a shape, a picture of it would do just fine.

It DOES need to be drawn on the fly.

It DOES HAVE to be a perfect semicircle.  Squishing it is unacceptable.

So what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DrawArrowArc(CentX As Single, CentY As Single, radius As Single, Ang1 As 
    Single, Ang2 As Single)
    Dim Arc As Shape    ' 
    'Draw 90-degree arc with radius = Radius and center at (CenterX,CenterY)
    Set Arc = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeArc, CentX, CentY - 
    radius,radius, radius)
    'Add arrowhead on clockwise end
    Arc.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadNone
    'adjust arrow to start at Ang1 and end at Ang2
    '(measured clockwise positive from vertical)
    Arc.Adjustments.Item(1) = 90 - Ang1
    Arc.Adjustments.Item(2) = 90 - Ang2
    Arc.ThreeD.RotationY = 180

End Sub

Sub CallDrawArrowArc()
    DrawArrowArc 0, -100, 100, -90, 90
End Sub
```